# Get country from data in column in dataframe python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, country-codes

I have an excel .csv file that contains a column called `Made From` that identifies the country/region e.g. `Made in Australia` or `Made in HK` or even with region `Made in APAC`

So my goal is to identify no matter which ISO country code or region name it is using. I want to put it into a new column called Country and another column called Region respectively.

Currently, I am trying this code to no avail. `df[Country] = df["Made From"].apply(lamda x:x if x in countries else "Global")`. The `countries` is an array of `countries = ["Australia", "Mexico"...]` that I wrote a bit of but no sure is there is a better way or solution out there that has a full list of all ISO codes and region names. If there are no standard region name, I could always do up a list as it is only naming a few regions.

Please help me on this as I am stuck here. Please let me know if there is any more clarification needed. Thank you.

I am coding in Python

UPDATE:
As requested, input data and expected output.

input

```
|Made From        |
-------------------
|Made in Australia|
|Made in HK       |
|Made in APAC     |
|UK Made          |
```

Expected Output

```
|Made From        |Country       |Region|
------------------------------------------
|Made in Australia|Australia     |APAC  |
|Made in HK       |Hong Kong     |APAC  |
|Made in APAC     |              |APAC  |
|UK Made          |United Kingdom|Europe|
```

Comment: please include copy and pasteable sample input data in dataframe format and expected output.

Comment: @DavidErickson Hi, thanks for the tip to show sample input and out. It think it made it clearer on what I want to get in the end. Thanks

Comment: How to get the information about the region in the cases of Australia and HK?

Comment: Hi @pythonic833 in this case, I was thinking of creating a dictionary e.g. RegCoun = { "APAC" : ['Hong Kong,...]...} but I don't think is feasible as I need to take into account ISO Code also

Comment: Need Help on this

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is ok if you can manage to create a complete countries list. Here is a small example:

```
import pandas as pd
import pycountry_convert as pc
import pycountry
from itertools import compress

continents = {
    'NA': 'North America',
    'SA': 'South America', 
    'AS': 'APAC',
    'OC': 'APAC',
    'AF': 'Africa',
    'EU': 'Europe'
}

regions = ["APAC", "EMEA", "NA", "SA"]

lc = list(pycountry.countries)

#It seems UK is not part of the ISO
exceptions = {"UK": "EMEA"}
countries = [lc[i].name for i in range(len(lc))] + \
            [lc[i].alpha_2 for i in range(len(lc))] + \
            [lc[i].alpha_3 for i in range(len(lc))] + ["UK"]
        
dataset = pd.DataFrame([[1,"Made in Australia"],[1,"Made in HK"],[1,"Made in APAC"], [1,"UK Made"]], 
                       columns = ["Other Columns", "Made From"])

# Assuming proper division of words
dataset["Countries"] = dataset["Made From"].apply(lambda x: [list(compress(x.split(" "), [x.split(" ")[i] in countries for i in range(len(x.split(" ")))])) + ["Global"]][0][0])
dataset["Regions"] = dataset["Made From"].apply(lambda x: [list(compress(x.split(" "), [x.split(" ")[i] in regions for i in range(len(x.split(" ")))])) + ["Local"]][0][0])

for i in range(len(dataset)):
    if dataset.iloc[i,3] == "Local":
        try:
            c = pc.country_name_to_country_alpha2(dataset.iloc[i,2], cn_name_format="default")
            c = pc.country_alpha2_to_continent_code(c)
            dataset.iat[i,3] = c
        except:
            try:
                c = pc.country_alpha2_to_continent_code(dataset.iloc[i,2])
                dataset.iat[i,3] = c
            except:
                try:
                    c = pc.country_alpha3_to_continent_code(dataset.iloc[i,2])
                    dataset.iat[i,3] = c                    
                except:
                    if dataset.iloc[i,2] in list(exceptions.keys()):
                        dataset.iat[i,3] = exceptions[dataset.iloc[i,2]]
        try:
            dataset.iat[i,3] = continents[dataset.iloc[i,3]]
        except:
            pass
dataset

    Other Columns   Made From           Countries   Regions
0   1               Made in Australia   Australia   APAC
1   1               Made in HK          HK          APAC
2   1               Made in APAC        Global      APAC
3   1               UK Made             UK          EMEA
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, saw the assumption you made. I am expecting my data to not be consistent so in the example input I showed UK Made, that could be one of the many ways that the data can have.

Comment: I am thinking along the lines of str.contains but I am not sure how to implement it here

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Your solution seems to be the closes one that I need. Just a few things I encountered that you could help enlighten me with. In the  `Made From` column if the country is `Made in United Kingdom` or `Made in South Korea` the `Countries` column doesn't seem to take in two-word countries `South Korea` it would just state Global.

Comment: Hey, in the case of `South Korea`, the name in pycountry is `'Korea, Republic of'`, so you should include in the `exceptions` list. For United Kingdom it should work since the name in pycountry is `'United Kingdom'`. Check if both words start with capital letter. Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: Also we are spliting by spaces, so other way to do that is to do conditional spliting for this specific cases of pairs of words.

Comment: What do you mean by conditional splitting for pair of words?

Comment: For example before everything you replace `United Kingdom` by `United_Kingdom` and you add `United_Kingdom` to the `exceptions` list.

Comment: I solved the issue by doing mapping and coming up with a country list. But I upvote this solution as it is really close to what I want but not the full answer. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you see that there are small number of non-country words in the column like ‘made’, ‘in’ and etc, you can use .str.replace to get rid of those words and then copy to the country column.

Then the second part is to standardise country names. That requires a list or dic to compare with.

Comment: Ideally, I want to directly deal with the country names or ISO codes as much as possible as there might be different non-country words being added in the future that might be a hassle to maintain

Comment: Ya if you know the country names are in some standard form, then your approach will be fine. If you know non country words in some standard way, what i proposed could be a viable solution. So you probably have to decide what’s best from your data